# Customization of default Microsoft Access combobox UI

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

In my combo box in Microsoft Access, I want to display not only the value or the key, but both of them.
For example:

1 Paris
2 London
3 New York

I found how to show these values in combo box at time of record selection (you retrieve 2 fields in SQL query), but I don't know how to show them after selection, what I can is to show or ID or value.
Of course, in DB table I want to write IDs only, the values are just for usability reasons.

Is there any way to implement such task?

Comment: Are you having trouble showing which item has been selected? It just shows ID? Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I want to show combobox with people's first & last name, in order to distinguish between «James Bond» I want to show also ID of each record, but I don't want to show something like «James Bond_1», I prefer to show value and ID without concatenation instead.

Comment: For what you want to do you need a query that looks like this: `SELECT ContactID, FirstName & " " & LastName, ContactID as ContactID2 FROM tblContacts ORDER BY FirstName, LastName` Then you need to set your combobox to have three columns. In the column widths you put 0";2";.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [HK1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504958/hk1), who proposed a right and worked solution:

> For what you want to do you need a query that looks like this: SELECT ContactID, FirstName & " " & LastName, ContactID as ContactID2 FROM tblContacts ORDER BY FirstName, LastName Then you need to set your combobox to have three columns. In the column widths you put 0";2";.5"

The issue is closed now.